# Modifying MWPhotoBrowser in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, subclassing

Hi I am have added the MWPhotoBrowser in my iPhone application it works great but now i need to add a little more functionality to my photo gallery.

basically what to do a couple things:

- add a button to the navigation bar
- decrease the space between two images.

However I don't know how to approach this problem.. should I subclass the Photo Browser or should I make changes in the Photo Browser's source code.

P.S. i tried to modify the code directly in MWPhotoBrowser.h file which didn't work. No changes were made. I'm super new to iPhone programming so i don't have much idea what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know its a noobish question so please go easy on down votes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MWPhotoBrowser.m file find the setNavBarAppearance method and add this

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self action:@selector(someAction)]; // This can be changed to your liking

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
[rightButton release];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was awesome it worked perfectly. I also want to decrease the space between two images, i.e when i slide from one image to another there should be very little gap between the two. if you know anything that would help me solve that please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set  the Padding : 10 to 0;

Its done.

Thnaks